# undefined al recorrer con each en ajax jquery - laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

tengo el siguiente problema:
estoy recorriendo con $.each para imprimir en blade, los datos que obtengo en consola con ajax son los correctos pero al querer imprimir en blade me muestra como undefined. Estoy trabajando con laravel en el backend

A la derecha el resultado en blade y a la izquierda los datos que obtengo en consola con ajax.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

utilizo AJAX y jquery para mostrar los datos en consola e imprimir en blade, el código es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(  function () {
    
    obtener_datos( );

    function obtener_datos( ) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('ajax.datos.index') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function ( data ) {
                mostrar_datos( data );
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON);
            }
        });

    }

    function mostrar_datos( datos ) {
        
        let HTML = "";

        $.each( datos, function( key, pagina ) {

            HTML += `
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4 content_new_time">
                    <div class="pricingTable">
                        <div class="pricingTable-header">
                            <h3 class="title">${pagina.id}</h3>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;

        });

        $("#container_html").html( HTML);
    }


});
```

ESTE ES EL MODELO
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTE ES EL RESOURCE
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTE ES EL CONTROLLER
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me causa ruido lo siguiente:  HTML = HTML +   por qué no solo pones  **HTML+=**

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar la forma en que respondes desde el servidor a esa petición Ajax?

Comment: He actualizado mi información, agradeceria su ayuda

Comment: El código va como texto por favor

Comment: concatena  puro javascritp amigo y te debe funcionar. <h3 class="title">'+pagina.id+'</h3>.  Recuerda blade es en el servidor y jv corre en el cliente.

Comment: Realmente no uso Laravel, pero lo que ocurre a mi juicio es que no estás enviando los datos bien organizados. He hecho una prueba simple con un array de objetos JSON como este: `[{"id":1}, {"id":2}]`  y el código funciona. Por tanto, desde Laravel, debes construir un array de objetos JSON y devolverlos al cliente, o cambiar la forma de lectura, según la estructura que mandes.

Comment: ok, muy agradecido

Comment: @EdelRojas la sintaxis del OP es válida, está usando template strings

Comment: @JhonGarcia puedes probar con: 1.- hacer un return response()->json() de la data que obtienes y/o enviar los headers necesarios indicando que la data que viaja al front es un json

Comment: @BetaM si eso funciona, lo que pasa es que ya habia utilizado en otro proyecto la misma forma que realicé mi pregunta y funcionaba bien, y hora que lo quiero emplear en otro proyecto no funciona, pero response()->json() funciona bien debido a que ya no utilizo el resource, muchas gracias por su ayuda amigos

Comment: Elimino mi comentario y si gustas publica tu solución

Answer (score 0):

el problema esta aqui  ${pagina.id}, porque colocas entre llaves y signo de dolar? esto es js

```
function mostrar_datos(datos) {
    
let html = "";

$.each(datos, function(key, pagina) {

    html += '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4 content_new_time">'
        html += '<div class="pricingTable">'
            html += '<div class="pricingTable-header">'
                html += '<h3 class="title">'
                html += pagina.id
            html += '</div>'        
        html += '</div>'
    html += '</div>'
    ;
}
```

}

te dejo el codigo mas organizado.

Saludos

Comment: El código es funcional así amigo te recomiendo leer sobre template strings en javascript por eso la sintaxis de ${}

Comment: Te recomiendo mucho leas [esto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)